# KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB' while installing basemap using conda install

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda, matplotlib-basemap

I want to use matplotlib basemap, using Anaconda in a Jupyter Notebook. while running this:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'PROJ_LIB'
```

What I've tried and haven't worked:

```
conda install basemap
```

and

```
conda install basemap -c conda-forge
```

I checked similar questions here but couldn't find a proper answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you already haven't found the solution, adding

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = '<path to anaconda>/anaconda3/share/proj'
```

to your code preamble will do the job.